# cropping sectors from all the images and saving them with different names in the loop

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-image

I am trying to crop the sectors from all the images(images contains circular objects) and trying to save them with different names in the loop.Here is my code with python 3.6 and scikit image

```
for filename in os.listdir("directory1"):
    image=io.imread(os.path.join("path1",filename))
'''get coordinates for polygon & circle,create masks for circle and polygon'''
'''(r0,c0),(r1,c1),(r2,c2) are circle center , coord's of sector''' 
  for k in range(7):
    imagevar=image
    rr, cc = draw.polygon([r0, r1[K], r1[K+1], r0],
                      [c0, c1[K], c1[K+1], c0], shape=mask_poly.shape)            
    mask_poly[rr, cc] = 1
    image_mask = mask_circle & mask_poly
    mk=numpy.logical_not(image_mask)
    imagevar[mk]=0
    path2='*pathforsamples*' #different from path1
    NewfileNameToSave = *path2*+fileNameToSave + '_'+ str(K+1) + '.jpg'
    io.imsave(NewfileNameToSave,imagevar)
    mask_poly[rr, cc] = 0
```

There is no problem with the filenames but I am having problems with the images. I get first sector from 1st 
iteration but from 2nd iteration, I get a black image and a warning which says "filename_2.jpg is a low contrast image". I guess first sector is being used for the remaining iterations even though i assigned "imagevar=image" at the beginning of the loop. So, is there any way to unload the image after "imsave" or any mistake in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution for my problem. In the second for loop, we can read the image again using imread